# Move multiple elements into one with FragmentTransaction SharedElement

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I'm using Android Jetpack's Navigation component and want to transition several elements into one when transitioning between fragments using FragmentTransaction SharedElement.
Example image:
[transition example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuoro.png)

I programmatically create a certain number (this number may vary) of views and add them to a container (LinearLayout) and attach an onClickListener to each view.

When clicked, I assign each view a transactionName and add it to Extras:

```kotlin
 
private fun factorAnalysisOnClick(factorData: FactorData) {
        val extrasBuilder = FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()

        binding.factorAnalysisContainer.children.forEach { fav ->
            fav.transitionName = FAV_TRANSITION_NAME
            extrasBuilder.addSharedElement(fav, "factorAnalysisView")
        }

        extrasBuilder.addSharedElement(binding.actionBar, "statisticByFactorActionBar")
        extrasBuilder.addSharedElement(binding.title,"title")
        val extras = extrasBuilder.build()


        findNavController().navigate(
            R.id.action_statistics_to_statistics_by_factor,
            bundleOf(
                Pair(KEY_FACTOR_DATA, factorData)
            ),
            null,
            extras
        )
    }
```

And I get the error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A shared element with the target name 'factorAnalysisView' has already been added to the transaction. at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(FragmentTransaction.java:679) at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:435) at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:398) at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:266) at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1867) at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1692) at site.pnpl.mira.ui.statistic.fragments.StatisticsFragment.factorAnalysisOnClick(StatisticsFragment.kt:171)`

I understand what he means, perhaps there is some way to implement this? Or maybe there are other ways to achieve the effect of a “stacked” view at the moment of transition?